# tf.keras.Sequential() Fails - Python Tensorflow Keras Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I think this error about cuda, Actually, i'm not sure.
There is a google colab link, you can run this from there.
Google colab link: [enter link description here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TOWopU6aDaTnT8DaBX-rIUPoYRjvP2Lp?usp=sharing)

```html
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense

(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

# reshape dataset to have a single channel
trainX = trainX.reshape((trainX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)) / 255.0
testX = testX.reshape((testX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)) / 255.0
# one hot encode target values
trainY = to_categorical(trainY, 10)
testY = to_categorical(testY, 10)

def define_model():
# create the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(5, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides = (1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(15, (5, 5), padding='valid', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10))

# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model

for bs in [64, 128, 256]:
model = define_model()
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size = 64)
_, acc = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)
print('batch size: %d > %.3f' % (bs, acc * 100.0))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It says

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

You have to move all the code lines of the method `def define_model()` a bit to the right. You have completely no indentation in your code. The same at the for loop. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/